# Comparing two variables

Tags: ruby, arrays

Am I comparing the pipe symbols |x| & |f| correctly below ?

|f| corresponds to the name of a dir
|x| corresponds to the name of a file

```
  Dir.foreach(@sortedFilesDir) do
  |f|
    @fileArray.each() {
      |x| 
      if(x.match(/^#{f}/))
        puts "match - "+x+","+f
      end
    }
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few changes:

1. I made the variable names more informative
2. I replaced the regular expression with String#start_with?
3. I made the code more functional-programming than imperative programming, by replacing two `each`s with a `map` and a `find`.
4. I used "#{expression}" rather than `"match - "+x+","+f`

I haven't checked that it works, though.

```
directory_names = Dir.foreach(@sorted_files_dir)
matching_directory_names = @file_array.map do |filename|
  directory_names.find do |directory_name|
    filename.start_with?("/" + filename + "/")
  end
end
@file_array.zip(matching_directory_names) do |filename, matching_directory_name|
  next if matching_directory_name.nil?
  puts "match - #{filename},#{matching_directory_name}"
end
```

I hope `directory_names` doesn't get calculated every time the loop gets run! If it does, then you might want `directory_names = Dir.foreach(@sorted_files_dir).to_a` at the start of the script.

Answer (score 1):

It is the general convention that you use the `do |var|` notation if your block is more than 1 line.  If it is 1 line, use the `{|var|}` syntax.

String interpolation is also preferred to concatenation as it uses less methods.

Another convention is that if your method doesn't take arguments, don't use the brackets at the end.  (Like you have done in your each method)

Also, in the ruby world, we usually underscore_our_variable_names instead of camelCasing them.  The exception being Constants (including class names) e.g. `MyClass` or `ThisIsOneOfMyConstants`

```
 Dir.foreach(@sorted_files) do |f|
    @file_array.each do |x| 
      if(x.match(/^#{f}/))
        puts "match - #{x},#{f}"
      end
    end
  end
```

You are using them correctly if your goal is to list files in the specified directory that match an entry in your @file_array.